# Get menu screenshot of the active window on Unity using python

Tags: python, menu, gtk, screenshot, wnck

I want to take a menu screenshot of the active window on Unity (Ubuntu environment). Preferably using Python. Right now I got the code which makes a screenshot of the active window using wnck and pygtk. Now, the problem is Unity keeps all the menus outside of the app's main window. That's why I need to find the way to capture the app's menus docked at unity panel as well. Any ideas? Here is the code I use to take a screenshot of the active window:

```
import gtk.gdk
import wnck

screen = wnck.screen_get_default()
screen.force_update()
activeWindow = screen.get_active_window()
activeWindowGeometry = activeWindow.get_geometry()

rootWindow = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()    
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,activeWindowGeometry[2],activeWindowGeometry[3])
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(rootWindow,rootWindow.get_colormap(),activeWindowGeometry[0],activeWindowGeometry[1],0,0,activeWindowGeometry[2],activeWindowGeometry[3])
pb.save("/tmp/screenshot.png","png")
```

Comment: If you use ubuntu, there is a nice tool to take a screenshot of the active window with a delay. Not a Python solution, but I think that would work.

Comment: I know about it, but I need to capture the screenshot programatically. I intend to use this solution as a library in a project. Besides, I don't want to capture entire screen - just the menu part.